# Frozen beef barley soup , adding more ingredients and re-freezing

Tags: beef, soup, barley

Frozen beef barley soup. Can I add more ingredients to thawed soup and safely re-freeze

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules for refreezing food](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/rules-for-refreezing-food)

Answer (score 1):

If you thaw your food in the fridge it is safe to add additional ingredients and re-freeze, but the quality will probably suffer. Don't thaw outside the fridge. You're better off freezing the new ingredients and combining them when you're ready to heat and serve them. Do your best to freeze as quickly as possible and with as little air in the containers as possible.